# Envers return QueryException on AuditReaderFactory query composite property

Tags: hibernate-envers

Envers cannot find composite property in Embedded class Audited. I have :

```
@Embeddable
public class Allocation {

   private Long value;

...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "payment")
@Audited
@AuditTable(value="payment_allocation")
public class PaymentEntity extends AbstractEntity {

   // All propert is not Audited except Allocation
   @Embedded
   @NotAudited
   private Transaction transaction;

   @Audited
   @Embedded
   private Allocation allocation;
...
}
```

So when I call :

```
AuditReaderFactory
            .get(entityManager)
            .createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(PaymentEntity.class, true, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.property("allocation.value").eq(1l))
            .getResultList();
```

I have a

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: allocation of: ....PaymentEntity_AUD

I try just "value" and I had same exception.

I want history of all Payments where value was 1L. So, There are something different to access a composite property like when we build a Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found solution on : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9178

the name of property not "allocation.value" but "allocation_value".

Comment: This is definitely something I want to consider changing in the future as I think its far more intuitive for users to work in terms of object paths much like JPA and Hibernate have traditionally done rather than putting the burden on users to use this underscore notation.  But glad you found the answer.